# Destructuring a Map

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

If I have an object in javascript like this:

```
let obj = {b: 3, c: 4, d: 6}
```

I can get the different parts out pretty easily if I destructure it, for example, I could just get c and d if I do:

```
let {c, d} = obj
```

Now this is great, but if I wanted to make a map:

```
let m = new Map()
m.set('b', 3).set('c', 4).set('d', 6)
```

I can get individual elements out with:

```
let c = m.get('c')
let d = m.get('d')
```

But is there any way to destructure an object like a map in the way that we did with a standard object. I find the syntax above so much simpler to use in many cases, that it actually serves as a pretty big disadvantage when using maps; despite the fact that you can get iterators by default and so on (list advantages here haha).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```js
const m = new Map();
m.set('b', 3)
 .set('c', 4)
 .set('d', 6);
 
const [[,b], [,c], [,d]] = m;

console.log(b, c, d);
```

```
const [[,b], [,c], [,d]] = m;
```

Comment: How does this work? Where is this documented? Explaining the code would be really helpful

Comment: When a Map instance is used with destructuring syntax, it will be "casted" to an array of [key, value] arrays, with respect to the order the map entries were added in the first place.

In this example, m would be "casted" to `[['b', 3], ['c', 4], ['d', 6]]`.

Then it’s only a matter of pattern-matching that value on the left-side, ignoring any unwanted values and collecting the rest: `const [[keyB, valueB], [keyC, valueC], [keyD, valueD]] = m;`, `const [[,foo], [bar,], [baz,ooka]] = m;`, etc.

Comment: Don't do this: it depends on the order Map entries.  If you switch the order in the array destructure, you get the wrong values: `const [[,c], [,d], [,b]] = m;`. Instead, use `const {...} = Object.fromEntries(m)` per @dfsq's answer or the `reduce` from @gurvinder372's answer.

Answer (score 13):

You can't destructure Map directly, you will have to either convert to object first or do something exotic, like using Proxy to intercept get calls. Something like this with helper function:

```js
function getFromMap (map) {
  return new Proxy(map, {
    get (obj, prop) {
      return obj.get(prop)
    }
  })
}

let m = new Map()
m.set('b', 3).set('c', 4).set('d', 6)

let { b, d } = getFromMap(m)
console.log(b, d)
```

Thanks to @Felix Favour for comment. Using recent [`Object.fromEntries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries) function intermediate conversion map to object can be simplified:

```
let { b, d } = Object.fromEntries(m)
```

Answer (score 3):

Convert `Map` to simple `object` first

```
var obj = [...m.entries()].reduce( (acc, c) => ( 
 acc[c[0]] = c[1], 
 acc), {}); //convert to object
```

Then you can destructure the same object

**Demo**

```js
let m = new Map()
m.set('b', 3).set('c', 4).set('d', 6);

var obj = [...m.entries()].reduce( (acc, c) => ( 
 acc[c[0]] = c[1], 
 acc), {}); //convert to object

//console.log(obj);
let { c, d } = obj; 
console.log(c, d);
```

Comment: Nice, but you can also destruct the `c` and make it inline: `[...(new Map([['a', 4], ['b', 2]])).entries()].reduce((acc, [key, value]) => (acc[key] = value, acc), {})`

Answer (score 1):

It's actually quite easy. In your code example,

```
let m = new Map()
m.set('b', 3).set('c', 4).set('d', 6)
```

you can just:

```
let a = [...m] // => [ [ 'b', 3 ], [ 'c', 4 ], [ 'd', 6 ] ]
```

or

```
let a = [...m.entries()] // same as above, more verbose
```

If you want to destruct individual values into b, c, d, we could:

```
let [b, c, d] = [...m.values()]
```

This would be the same as @Salih's answer, but a bit more readable.

Answer (score 1):

Construct `Object.fromEntries` and destructor it:

```js
const map = new Map();
map.set('a', 3)
   .set('b', 4)
   .set('c', 6);

// to destructure
const {a, b, c } = Object.fromEntries(map);
console.log("a:", a, ", b:", b, ", c:", c); // a: 3 , b: 4 , c: 6
```

[MDN documentation is here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries)

Answer (score 0):

There's no built-in way to destructure a Map, the only thing to do would be to explicitly convert it to an object first:

```js
const m = new Map();
m.set('b', 3)
  .set('c', 4)
  .set('d', 6);
const { b, c, d } = mapToObj(m);
console.log(d);

function mapToObj(inputMap) {
  const obj = {};
  for (const [key, value] of m) obj[key] = value;
  return obj;
}
```

But if your keys are known beforehand, and aren't added/removed frequently, there might not be much benefit to using a Map - just use a standard Object instead and you can destructure natively.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `getMultiple()` that returns an object with the keys you want, and then destructure the results:

```js
const m = new Map([['b', 3], ['c', 4], ['d', 6]]);

const getMultiple = (m, ...keys) => Object.assign(...keys.map(k => ({ [k]: m.get(k) })))

const { b, d } = getMultiple(m, 'b', 'd')

console.log('b', b)
console.log('d', d)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const map = new Map([['a',1],['b',2],['c',3]]);

const arr = [...map.values()];
```

Comment: Please consider adding an explanation of what you have just written.

Answer (score -2):

What about...

```js
const mapAnObj = () => {
  const obj = { b: 3, c: 4, d: 6 }

  return Object.keys(obj).map(elem => obj[elem]);
};

console.log(mapAnObj());
```

Maybe I am not understanding the question correctly, correct me If I'm wrong but this would grant you the very same results, and it's effective and quick.

Comment: OP is talking about the Map object, not the map function: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map